# Scala non-consecutive sub-array

Tags: arrays, scala, slice

I'm new to Scala.  I see that there's a `slice` method for Arrays that can return a consecutive slice, like so:

```
scala> "zero|one|two|three|four|five".split("\\|").slice(2,5)
res3: Array[String] = Array(two, three, four)
```

Is there syntactic sugar somewhere for taking an arbitrary, non-consecutive, non-ascending sub-array?  Something like:

```
scala> "zero|one|two|three|four|five".split("\\|").fictionalMethod(4,1,5)
res3: Array[String] = Array(four, one, five)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shortest line using only standard library functions I can think of would be

```
Array(4, 1, 5) map "zero|one|two|three|four|five".split("\\|")
```

Comment: Would that end up splitting the string multiple times, once per array index?

Comment: By splitting the string, I should have said "re-evaluating `"zero|one|two|three|four|five".split("\\|")`" multiple times.

Comment: In this case no, it won't -- but you're right that it's precariously close to doing so. `Array(4, 1, 5) map "(zero|one|two|three|four|five".split("\\|").apply(_))` would evaluate multiple times.

Comment: Can't you skip the `apply` as well? Works fine for me without it.

Comment: +1 clever reverse thinking - i.e. give the indices before the operation